# Importing html files with es6 template string loader

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to import my templates into my js with [es6 template string loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-template-string-loader). The only difference in my case is that I don't want to include css, only html. My code is as follows:

```
import app from '../../bootstrap.js';
import template from './header.html';

app.component('siteHeader', {
  template
});
```

and my error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I recently needed to do the same thing, and this is how I did it.

**1.** I used the npm module [`html-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader), instead of `es6-template-string-loader`

**2.** Add to `webpack.config.js`

## Webpack 3

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {loader: 'html-loader'}
        }
    ]
}
...
```

## Webpack 1 (deprecated, but from original answer):

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html-loader"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

**3.** Use in your JS files

```
import template from './header.html';
```

Comment: Gives error "Cannot find module" on `import template from './header.html';`

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, is your html file named `header.html`, and is it located in the same directory as the JS file you're importing into? Also, what version of webpack are you using?

Comment: Using webpack 3.5.6. Yes using same name

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, do you have a resolve root set on the webpack config? Also, if you could add your webpack.config to a JsFiddle or something, I can take a better look

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, I get the same error when the path or filename isn't right. If the JS file and the HTML file are in the same directory, is the `.` at the beginning of the path (`./header.html`)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154468/discussion-between-kevbot-and-shyamal-parikh).

Comment: So, restarting the PC solved the issue. Facing another issue, .js file compiled contains `var html = template.default`, where the default property is empty, it should be just `template`. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Needed to set exportAsDefault flag

Comment: I get : Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-loader' in 'C:\dev\front-angle2\src'

Answer (score 7):

The solution posted here is correct. Just adding an info to the error i faced when implementing the solution mentioned.

I got the error:  TS2307: Cannot find module './index3.html'
This was because of typescript compilation error. 
The work around was [here](https://medium.com/@sampsonjoliver/importing-html-files-from-typescript-bd1c50909992)

Had to define a file:  html.d.ts containing the below

```js
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [Raw Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader).

Your webpack configuration will contain this:

```
...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tpl.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    }
...
```

In your code write

```
import tpl from './mytemplate.html';
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume your `webpack.config.js` is along the lines of this:

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "es6-template-string"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

The problem is that `template-string-loader` outputs an exported template string function using ES6 syntax. You'll still need to pass that through babel.

Your configuration should look something like this:

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "babel?presets[]=es2015!es6-template-string"
        }
    ]
}
...
```

To use it you need to call is as a function:

```
import app from '../../bootstrap.js';
import template from './header.html';

app.component('siteHeader', {
   template()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `raw-loader` instead of `text-loader`, because it has much more contributors and it's officially mentioned on the webpack documentation: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/

It's a safer choice on the long run. Download link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-loader

**webpack.config.js**

```
 module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(tpl|txt)(\?.*)?$/,
            use: 'raw-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Now, I can use it to load a template file **as a string** for  my components, like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyTemplate from './template.tpl'

Vue.component('my-component',{
   'template' : MyTemplate
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
module: {  
          loaders: [  
           {  
              test: /\.html$/,  
              loader: 'html-loader?exportAsEs6Default',  
           }  
      ]  
  }
```

More info on this config syntax can be read in `html-loader` repo readme

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#export-formats