# How to load external html as template or x-template in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Since Vue allows to use x-template as component's template, so I wonder how can I import external html like javascript, rather than write all template html inline within that x-template tag?

For example, if I write something like this in index.html:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="user-data-editor">
    <div class="user-data-editor">
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

It can be referred in Vue component by `template:"#user-data-editor"`

But when I try to write those html into another file like:

**user-data-editor.html**

```
<div class="user-data-editor">
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

And try to use it in **index.html** like:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="user-data-editor" src="user-data-editor.html"></script>
```

It will stop working. I wonder where is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Not using vue-cli?

Comment: According to mdn script document. if you specific <script type="other value">, "The src attribute will be ignored".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 1):

Like said tianzhipeng, you can't load a script which is not a javascript file with [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> #### `type`
>
> This attribute indicates the type of script represented. The value of this attribute will be in one of the following categories:
>
> - **Omitted or a JavaScript MIME type**: This indicates the script is
>   JavaScript. The HTML5 specification urges authors to omit the
>   attribute rather than provide a redundant MIME type. In earlier
>   browsers, this identified the scripting language of the embedded or
>   imported (via the `src` attribute) code. JavaScript MIME types are
>   [listed in the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#javascript_types).
> - **module**: Causes the code to be treated as
>   a JavaScript module. The processing of the script contents is not
>   affected by the charset and defer attributes. For information on using
>   module, see our [JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) guide. Unlike classic scripts,
>   module scripts require the use of the CORS protocol for cross-origin fetching.
> - **Any other value**: The embedded content is treated as a data block which won't be processed by the browser. Developers must use a valid MIME type that is not a JavaScript MIME type to denote data blocks. The `src` attribute will be ignored.
>   <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type)</sup>

To load another mime type, you have to use webpack and some loader

See [Importing html files with es6 template string loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818401/importing-html-files-with-es6-template-string-loader)