# How do I load a Vue template from a hosted html file (no webpack, etc)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying a new way of writing my ui and I am using straight ESM loading with Vue. As such I am trying to load my HTML files like I would with say Webpack. I have a [simple example](https://plnkr.co/edit/lf8vcJyN1lZXPJ4XKx4U?p=preview) of what I am talking about. I basically want to take...

```
export default {
    template: "<div>Here is the component. I want this template to be an html file without webpack</div>" 
    // I want this to be from a url say mysite.net/viewport.html
}
```

I tried the simple things like

```
import Template from "/viewport.html"
```

But of course that didn't work

I think there might be something I can do with dynamic components. Has anyone tried this an come up with a good solution?

Comment: have you setup HTML loader? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818401/importing-html-files-with-es6-template-string-loader

Comment: You could use [X-Templates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#X-Templates) and reference the template by an id.

Comment: Any chance you could fork the plunker and show me a simple example?