# How to render a static html page in ReactJS?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to render an html page in react. I have tried multiple solutions but still, I am getting an error. Yes I know there are many questions similar to this one but none of those solutions has worked for me. I am using reactjs as front-end and simply trying to show a static html page.

html file is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ably WebRTC Video call Demo</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.temasys.io/adapterjs/0.15.x/adapter.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.temasys.io/adapterjs/0.15.x/adapter.screenshare.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.ably.io/lib/ably.min-1.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-peer/9.1.2/simplepeer.min.js"></script>

    <script src="ably-screenshare.js"></script>

    <script src="connection-helper.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 5em;">
      <div class="container" id="join">
        <h4 id="online">Users online (0)</h4>

        <ul id="memberList"></ul>
      </div>

      <div class="container" id="call" style="display:none;">
        <video width="320" height="240" id="local" controls></video>

        <video width="320" height="240" id="remote" controls></video>

        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="handleEndCall()">
          End call
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <style>
    small {
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

and the solution that I tried is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
var __html = require("./screen.html");
var template = { __html: __html };

class ScreenShare extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="screen-share">
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ScreenShare;
```

Even using the above solution, I am getting this error

```
./src/components/screenShare/screen.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <!DOCTYPE html>
| 
| <html>
```

is there something wrong that I am doing? I know dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not the best way to solve the issue but I tried to change the above html code into react component and it didn't help. So I tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML to convert it but it is still giving error.

Comment: Duplication of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818401/importing-html-files-with-es6-template-string-loader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing html files with es6 template string loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37818401/importing-html-files-with-es6-template-string-loader)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, importing an HTML file with react will not work. Given your use case and the route which you want to go, the best bet will be to convert the HTML page to a js file and then export for example:

html.js file

```
module.exports = `<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ably WebRTC Video call Demo</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.temasys.io/adapterjs/0.15.x/adapter.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.temasys.io/adapterjs/0.15.x/adapter.screenshare.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.ably.io/lib/ably.min-1.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/simple-peer/9.1.2/simplepeer.min.js"></script>

    <script src="ably-screenshare.js"></script>

    <script src="connection-helper.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 5em;">
      <div class="container" id="join">
        <h4 id="online">Users online (0)</h4>

        <ul id="memberList"></ul>
      </div>

      <div class="container" id="call" style="display:none;">
        <video width="320" height="240" id="local" controls></video>

        <video width="320" height="240" id="remote" controls></video>

        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="handleEndCall()">
          End call
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <style>
    small {
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</html>`;
```

Here, note the module.exports, as well as the template string used, so you can call it in your react page this way:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
var __html = require('./index.html.js');
var template = { __html: __html };

class ScreenShare extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="screen-share">
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ScreenShare;
```

Comment: it initially allowed to compile the project if I remove html and head tags. But it still doesn't parse the code and the whole page collapse.

Comment: This answer is not 100% true. Since it is using dangerouslySetInnerHTML It doesn't run the code inside the script tags. In order to run the code inside the sciprt tags I use react-helmet component.

Comment: `require` is not defined for me.

Answer (score 6):

Put your static file in the public folder then in your routing section put this:

```
<Route exact path="/">
   <Redirect push to={"/home.html"} />
</Route>
```

Comment: I tested and it works. You can add reload or refresh to route.

Comment: Note that in v6, this component is called Navigate as opposed to Redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your HTML static file to string and pass it to your div with dangerouslySetInnerHTML tag.
Then if you have a problem again, in this case, your HTML file might have a field that is not defined or not true.
Check your HTML and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).